# How to use python to elegantly parameterize a SQL DELETE statement?

Tags: python

I have a list of user_ids to be deleted:
The user_ids are `str` type.

```py
users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Currently I'm deleting them with these codes

```py
query_delete = 'delete from users where user_id in ({});'.format('?, '*len(users))
# delete from users where user_id in (?, ?, ?, );

query_delete.replace(", )", ")")
# delete from users where user_id in (?, ?, ?);

cursor.execute(query_delete, users)
```

I think use the `.format('?, '*len(users))` to paramize the query is not elegant enough.
Is there a better way to make the code more elegantly and readable?

**EDIT**
I'm using python 3.6.5 on CentOS 7, and MySQL 8.
I want the query executed as

```sql
delete from users where user_id in ('user1', 'user2', 'user3');
```

Comment: What version of Python 3 are you using and what do you want the SQL statement to look like?

Comment: @martineau updated the question. In fact what I want is to make the query looks better when use a `where col in ()` clause to match a list.

Comment: `'?, '*len(users)` replace with `'?,'*len(users)[:-1]`, then you don't need `query_delete.replace(", )", ")")`

Comment: @AndrejKesely, do you know if there is a better way to pass the list of user_ids to the query with a `where col in ();` clause in `cursor.execute()`  instead of using the `*len(users)`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what database and database interface library you are using, it might be easier to use the parameter-passing mechanism of the library. For example, with PostgreSQL and psycopg2, something like this should work:

```
users = [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' ]
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = ANY (%(u)s)",
               { 'u': users })
```

(typed without testing, so probably full of trivial mistakes).

This would also eliminate the risk of SQL injections.